# How to get value of json field in django views.py

Tags: python, django

[views.py]

```
from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')
histories = History.objects.filter(content__icontains='teacher', date__gte=from_date, date__lte=to_date).order_by('date')
for h in histories:
    histories = History.objects.annotate(teacher=json.loads(h.summary)).values('study_name', 'teacher', 'date')
```

I am trying to print the 'study_name', 'summary', and 'date' fields of the History model that satisfy the period set in Django views.py .
The summary field uses json.loads as the json type, but the following error occurs.

QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): {'field_summary': {'recruiting': 'None -> Yes', 'teacher': 'None -> Halen', 'subject': 'None -> 'science'}, 'file_summary': {}}.

How to get the teacher value of field_summary?

Comment: Is `summary` not already the JSON value you want? What exactly are you trying to do? Please share the relevant parts of your model and expected output.

Comment: I am trying to get the teacher value in the summary field. The summary field is a json type and I am curious about the extraction method using annotate .

Comment: As you said, I obviously created the summary field as json type, but when I checked by creating get_type templatetag from template, it was "str" type. How do I get the teacher value for str ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
import json
teacher_value = json.load(histories.teacher)
```

Comment: an error occurs: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'teacher'

Comment: send me your models.py code, you may if you like as well upvote my answer x)